# Web farm framework causes IIS to crash

Tags: iis-7.5, arr, iis

I am having some issues after installation of ARR, and WFF on the controller server when I try and expand the servers node underneath web farms in IIS manager, IIS crashes and I get the following error:

IISMANAGER_CRASH

IIS Manager terminated unexpectedly.

Exception:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index

Any ideas where I could go to get some help in resolving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here http://forums.iis.net/t/1173083.aspx pointed us in the right direction. 
We had web deploy 2 and 3 installed, we uninstalled both and re-installed 3 and everything came good.